# cocos2d v2.x missing from template selector after upgrade

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I was using cocos2d v1 for iPhone. When Steffen Itterheim's Learn cocos2d 2 book was published, I installed Kobold2D v 2.0.4. The book suggests adding new files to a project by using the cocos2d v2.x or the Kobold2D template classes, but neither show up in XCode! It still simply has cocos2d as a template class. Does this matter greatly?
Thanks